# Can we use wildcard in the field_name or can we apply condition in fields block inside query_string?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following questions related to the elastic search:-

1. Can we use the **wildcard in the fields name in term block** in the query? If not is there any alternate way to achieve this? Like In the below query I want to achieve something like this.

   ````
       "must": [
                   {
                     "term": {
                       "*_sold.Type": "Type XYZ"
                     }
                   }
           ]
     }```
   ````
2. How we can apply condition in **"fields"** in **query_string** block? e.g I have this part of query I want that if type of attribute is Type XYZ then only we need to search into this attribute.

   ```
   {
             "query_string": {
               "query": "data",
               "type": "best_fields",
               "fields": [
                 "date",
                 "id_number",
                 "type",
                 "*__Sold.*"  // here I want that if "*_Sold.Type" == "Type XYZ" then only seach inside this attributes otherwise skip it.  
               ],
               "lenient": true,
               "default_operator": "AND",
               "boost": 3
             }
   ```

   }

**Here is the sample document.**

```
    {
            "_index" : "_dev",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "data-2",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "type" : "datas",
              "id_number" : 736762732784934,
              "date" : "2011-01-26",
              "Service_Sold" : [
                {
                  "Type" : "Type XYZ",
                  "Service_Name" : "Service XYZ"
                }
              ],
              "Product_Sold" : [
                {
                  "Type" : "Type ABC",
                  "Product_Name" : "Product ABC"
                }
              ]
              "Item_Sold" : [
                {
                  "Type" : "Type XYZ",
                  "Item_Name" : "Item XYZ"
                }
              ]
              ...
              50 other attributes
  }
```

Note: 7.10 version elastic-seach running queries on KIBANA. We can also upgrade our version if required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) which allows you to achieve what you are looking for.
You query should look like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "*_sold.Type"
      ],
      "query": "Type XYZ"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to search in all the fields inside the attribute like for 'Service_Sold' attribute i want to search in 'Service_Name' and other field also if and only if its Type is 'Type XYZ'. but the above query will search 'Type XYZ' string only in Type fields of the attribute...